# Entityfrom spam protection module without captcha

Tags: entities

Is there a module which I can use with entity forms without needing captcha field?

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for [Hidden CAPTCHA](https://drupal.org/project/hidden_captcha).

Even though you need the CAPTCHA module for this, Hidden CAPTCHA module will not display any captcha field and you don't absolutely need to have a human enter a text, number, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For spam protection on [Entityforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform), you can use [Honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot) and [Honeypot Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot_entityform) to add an invisible "honeypot" field to your Entityform Types.

It's a simple and unobtrusive alternative to the [CAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) module and effortless to configure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Mollom](https://www.drupal.org/project/mollom) module, which has native integration with Entityforms and offers spam protection among [many other features](https://www.mollom.com/features).

[image: Entityform Spam Protection using Mollom]